# Implementing follower relations in Android using parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my app, I'm using parse.com as the backend. I want to implement user follow relation, as in a user can follow another user. I am try to do this by getting the secondary user and adding the current user as a follower using the parse relation object. I always get an exception saying that I can update any field for a user who is not authenticated (signed in officially) because every user is protected. So, I searched for other ways to achieve this follow relationship but couldn't find anything. I just need someone to point me in the right direction, if there is another way to implement this.

Comment: You can use Cloud Code and use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` before doing any operation. This will perform the operation as admin.

Comment: thanks @Ralphilius, I haven't used the cloud code before, so i don't know how to modify user objects with it. Can you please provide something that i can work with? thanks.